# resize an object in three.js / Autodesk 3D Viewer (Autodesk Forge Viewer)

Tags: canvas, three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

How do I resize and move or translate an object?

This change is such that I have to move the curtain up or down

I need to **resize** or **position** an object Animated or in one place (no difference)

**viewer3D : LMV v3.3.6**

> try 1:

```
oViewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, onSelectedCallback);
function onSelectedCallback(event) {
    var fragId = oViewer.getSelection()[0];
    if (typeof fragId == 'undefined') {return; }
    var fragIdsArray = (Array.isArray(fragId) ? fragId : [fragId]);

    fragIdsArray.forEach(function (subFragId) {

        var mesh = oViewer.impl.getRenderProxy(oViewer, subFragId);
        var mtx_for_method1 = mesh.matrixWorld.elements;
        mtx_for_method1[12] += 10;
        mtx_for_method1[13] += 20;
        mtx_for_method1[14] += 30;

    });

    oViewer.impl.invalidate(true);
}
```

> try 2:

```
oViewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, onSelectedCallback);
function onSelectedCallback(event) {
    var fragId = oViewer.getSelection()[0];
    if (typeof fragId == 'undefined') {return; }
    var fragIdsArray = (Array.isArray(fragId) ? fragId : [fragId]);
    fragIdsArray.forEach(function (subFragId) {
        var mesh = oViewer.impl.getRenderProxy(oViewer, subFragId);
            var transMat = new THREE.Matrix4();
            var m1 = new THREE.Matrix4();
            var m2 = new THREE.Matrix4();
            var m3 = new THREE.Matrix4();
            var alpha = 0;
            var beta = Math.PI;
            var gamma = Math.PI / 2;
            m1.makeRotationX(alpha);
            m2.makeRotationY(beta);
            m3.makeRotationZ(gamma);
            transMat.multiplyMatrices(m1, m2);
            transMat.multiply(m3);
            var mtx_for_method2 = mesh.matrixWorld;
            mtx_for_method2.multiply(transMat);
            mtx_for_method2.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate = True;
    });

    oViewer.impl.invalidate(true);
}
```

**Is this possible?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can but can see there's a few issues with your code and they are:

- Use get the fragments using `instanceTree.enumNodeFragments`, `viewer.getSelection` only gets you the `dbids` of the component(s) currently selected

**Edit:**

- Use the fragment proxy instead of the mesh proxy...

```
const model = NOP_VIEWER.model;
model.getData().instanceTree.enumNodeFragments(
      dbid, fragId => {
        const fragProxy = NOP_VIEWER.impl.getFragmentProxy(model, fragId);
        fragProxy.scale = new THREE.Vector3(1.1,1.1,1.1);
        fragProxy.updateAnimTransform()
    });
NOP_VIEWER.impl.invalidate(true)
```

Comment: The object becomes too large and not scalable

Comment: thanks man I solved the problem with your help and here's the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57970267/how-to-resize-on-object-autodesk-3d-viewer-a360

Comment: and your solution is quite right and it works, Thanks <3